# how to resolve solr create aliase error URI is too large?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm creating an aliase using solr

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=testalias&collections=anotherCollection,testCollection

now if collection list goes beyond 300 collection's then solr is throwing "URI is too Large" exception.
While researching i have found a solution to make POST request but solr has GET request for create aliase API.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit exactly the same parameters as a POST request insted. It'll work the same as when the parameters are submitted as a GET request.

The use case is exactly this - many times the set of parameters sent for a query exceeds the allowed URI length.